# Getting 'Cannot insert duplicate key' from UPDATE query

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I'm writing an ODBC class to connect to a remote SQL Server database. I have most of it working.

The class has the ability to generate queries such as the following:

> UPDATE Customers SET Id=?,Name=?,TaxId=?,ContactFName=?,ContactLName=?,Phone_Office=?,Phone_Mobile=?,Phone_Home=?,Email=?,Website=?,Address1_Physical=?,Address2_Physical=?,City_Physical=?,State_Physical=?,Zip_Physical=?,Address1_Billing=?,Address2_Billing=?,City_Billing=?,State_Billing=?,Zip_Billing=?,StartingBalance=?,Discount=?,BillingSequence=?,BillingCategory=?,ShowOnReport=?,Active=?,CreateDate=?

As you can see, it's an UPDATE query. Yet, running this query gives me an error:

> Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (SQL Server) : ReturnCode: -1 : Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Customers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Customers'. The duplicate key value is (82). (State: 23000, NativeError: 2627) : The statement has been terminated. (State: 01000, NativeError: 3621)

I'm confused why I'm getting an error about inserting when I'm doing an update. Has anyone seen this?

Notes:

- *`Id` is the primary key. I first read all column values from the database, and then update those I want to change. The ID does **not** change.*
- *The error above was put together by my code, but is based on the messages returned by `SQLGetDiagRec()`.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no WHERE clause on the UPDATE statement, so it's trying to update EVERY SINGLE ROW in the database, and since ID is one of the columns being changed, it's trying to set every row's ID to the same value. This is resulting in an attempt to create a duplicate primary key.

Make sure your UPDATE statement has an appropriate WHERE clause... like "WHERE ID = ?"... and it's probably best practice to NOT include the ID in that UPDATE statement if it's not changing.

Comment: D'oh! I'm so far into the technical details, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

That is the message you should expect when an UPDATE statement violates a primary key.  EG

```
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists t

create table t(id int primary key)

insert into t(id) values (1),(2)

go

update t set id = 2 where id = 1
--Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 11
--Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__t__3213E83F127C5D76'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.t'. The duplicate key value is (2).
--The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the UPDATE I see a field called ID.  If you are making a change to the ID and it's the primary key then the DBMS will fuss because you are trying to store duplicate keys.

Comment: If the ID doesn't change then I suggest taking it out of the update and see what message you get.